# AspectJ Control Flow/Multiple Joinpoints

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to learn AspectJ and figuring out how to retrieve specific joinpoints at certain points in a flow. My example is something like this:

I want to run an unit test annotated with JUnit's `@Test` then any methods called in that test that may be in another class annotated with another annotation, let's say `@Example`, then I could access basically the entire flow at those certain points so I had the ability to get the class name/method name of the test annotated with `@Test` and then also get the method information for the method annotated `@Example`. I've included some example code for clarification:

Test class:

```
public class ExampleTest {
  @Test
  public void shouldTestSomething() {
    ExampleClass exampleClazz = new ExampleClass();
    exampleClazz.something();
    // ...
  }
```

POJO:

```
public class ExampleClass {
  @Example
  public void something() {
    // do something
  end
end
```

So with these classes, I would like to make an aspect that would basically find any kind of `@Example` called within a `@Test` so I can then have access to both (or more) join points where I can grab the method/class signatures from the AspectJ `JoinPoint` object.

I tried something like this:

```
@Aspect
public class ExampleAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(@org.junit.Test * *(..)) 
             && !within(ExampleAspect)")
  public void testPointCut() {}

  @Pointcut("@annotation(com.example.Example)")
  public void examplePointCut() {}

  @After("cflow(testPointCut) && examplePointCut()")
  public void doSomething(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature());
  }
}
```

But the output looks like this:

```
void ExampleTest.ExampleClass.something()
```

The main issue is that it is missing the name of the test method (**shouldTestSomething()**) in the signature. What would be the best way to retrieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you need to access information about the context from where a piece of code under a join point of your interest gets called, then what you need is the `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart` (in native AspectJ syntax). If you are using AspectJ 5 annotation style aspects, just add a parameter to your advice method with the type `JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart`.

Note that this is not available for `execution()` style pointcuts, only for `call()` style pointcuts, otherwise the `JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart` and `JoinPoint.StaticPart` will be the same.

This means you need to rewrite your aspect in the following way:

```
@Aspect
public class ExampleAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(@org.junit.Test * *(..)) && !within(ExampleAspect)")
    public void testPointCut() {
    }

    @Pointcut("call(@com.example.Example * *(..))")
    public void examplePointCut() {
    }

    @After("cflow(testPointCut()) && examplePointCut()")
    public void doSomething(JoinPoint joinPoint, EnclosingStaticPart enclosingStaticPart) {
        System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature() + " was invoked from "
            + enclosingStaticPart.getSignature());
    }

}
```

The output with your test code would be:

`void q35991663.com.example.ExampleClass.something() was invoked from void q35991663.com.example.ExampleTest.shouldTestSomething()`

I also rewrote your `examplePointCut`. The pointcut expression `@annotation(com.example.Example)` would mean

> any join point where the subject has an annotation of type `com.example.Example`

which would include both `execution()` and `call()` type join points. We need only the `call()` join points in this case, so `@annotation()` isn't even necessary if you are not planning to bind the value of the annotation to the advice context.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the explanations on using `call()` instead of `execution()` as well.